# What exactly is +VCC and -VCC in op amps?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I was reading about op amps and got confused at the supply voltage part. If I connect a 9 V battery as supply does that mean +VCC is 9 and -VCC is 0 or +VCC is 9 and -VCC is also -9? And also the max supply voltage given in data sheets, what are they referenced to, with respect to ground or -VCC?

[image: Datasheet example]

Comment: Most op.amps do not have ground connection, so, it is your choice, which voltage to use as zero in your circuit. Requirements is that voltages on all terminals are in allowable ranges. For example from 6 to 36 V between power supply terminals and voltages on inputs are within power supply voltages

Answer (score 3):

If you have one 9V battery then obviously you cannot have +9V, 0V and -9V which needs two 9V batteries.
Do it like this:
[image: opamps]